# Проблема со скриптом, обрабатывающим transform в css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Всем привет. Кто может подсказать - header страницы.
Во всю высоту и ширину изображение(`position: fixed`), в центре изображения текст(назовем его -"логотип").
Необходимо, чтобы при скролле страницы логотип постепенно спускался вниз. Использую вот эту функцию:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
var st = $(this).scrollTop(); 
$(".logos").css({ 
"transform" : "translate(0%," + st/3 + "%" 
}); 
});
```

Все вроде бы хорошо, в Mozilla работает норм, а вот в остальных браузерах(Chrom,Opera,IE) логотип опускается постепенно, но это происходит не плавно как в Mozilla, а рывками, как по ступенькам.
Есть мысль как это решить?Возможно проблема в кроссбраузерных префиксах, но пробовал писать и с префиксом под конкретный браузер, результат тот же.

Comment: sоrry, transform

Comment: Вы можете править свой вопрос. Ниже текста вопроса ссылка Править.

Comment: Возможно, это из-за трансформ, попробуйте может с помощью position: relative менять значение top/bottom.

Comment: Сергей, мне не подойдет такой вариант..я пробовал..Я понимаю что дело в трансформации поэтому и задал тут вопрос..Не знаю как решить..

Comment: Может поможет will-change ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Comment: закрывающуюю скобку забыли поставить в translate. округлять `st/3` пробовали?

Comment: закрывающая скобка в данном случае не нужна,код правилен и нигде ошибки не выдает(ни до ни  после него,ни в нем).а вот на тему округлять-это стесняюсь спросить как?он к переменной st привязан и значение которое получается от этого выражения как раз то, что нужно, ни больше ни меньше.ПОвторюсь-в mozilla работает без всяких проблем, а в остальных браузерах работает, но смещается скачками..то есть паралакс получается не плавный!вот в этом проблема только.

Comment: А вот на тему will-change - а что в нем нужно прописать тогда?не сталкивался с ним...сейчас конечно документацию прочитаю...Хотя полагаю что проблему это не решит, как я понял из беглого взгляда, оно браузер лишь предупреждает об ожидаемом изменении, а тут получается проблема в ходе самого изменения(работы скрипта)..

Comment: @Deniskins, у вас st/3 в большем количестве случаев не целое число, из-за разного типа сглаживания в браузерах как раз и может дергаться. `Math.round(st/3)`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, попробовал вариант,это не помогло..

Comment: Я уже подумываю, может вообще отключить данную функцию для IE, вот только как оформить это не знаю...условные ссылки тут не вариант..мне предложили подключить detect.js, но не пользовался им, надо разбираться...

Answer (score 1):

В какой-то степени решил вопрос - у меня был подключен plugins-scroll, для смягчения скролла страниц...отключил его и в chrome и opera заработало нормально все, а вот в IE так и скачет..так что вопрос только в IE остался.Если есть мысли у кого какие, то посоветуете, что делать, буду признателен.